# Apps not showing from other Google account in the Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, 7.0-nougat

I had one main Google account on my phone, I installed all of my apps through the play store on that account. I am running HTCs version of Android 7.0

I recently changed to a new Google account (removed the old one and signed into the new one). I look on the play store to update my apps and it gets stuck on looking for updates. It also gets stuck on loading when I tap on installed apps.

How do I get app updates back?

EDIT: All android pre-installed apps are showing up now (chrome, Google, etc.) But apps installed on the other Google account are still not showing.

Comment: Afraid only by switching back to your original account – as that's what your apps etc. are bound to. What you missed to include with your question: Have you *replaced* the account on your device (i.e. dropped the old one and setup only the new one), or configured the new account additionally?

Comment: Completely dropped the old account. No longer on device

Comment: Then there you have the cause. You could add it back as secondary account – at least if you had any apps bought with it and want to keep those working. If it's only free apps, you could just wait a little; it should find them pretty soon (usually takes no longer than 24h for this). At least that's what happens with apps installed from other sources; I'm not sure if the framework gets confused with apps it had already bound to a (no longer existing) other account.